# how to delete a blank frame in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this function that creates a "frame" or something like a frame and i want to delete it.

Here is the code for the create:

```
function disableIframe()
{
    var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
    d = document.createElement('iframe');

    var width = iframe.offsetWidth;
    d.style.width = width + 'px';

    var height = iframe.offsetHeight ;
    d.style.height = height + 'px';

    var top = iframe.offsetTop;
    d.style.top = top + 'px';

    var left = iframe.offsetLeft - 140;
    d.style.left = left + 'px';

    d.style.position = 'absolute';
    // d.onclick="event.cancelBubble = true;"
    d.style.opacity = '100';
    d.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=0)';
    d.style.display="block";
    d.style.background = 'black';
    d.style.zIndex = '100';
    d.id = 'd';
    d.tagName = 'd';
    iframe.offsetParent.appendChild(d);
}
```

I tried to delete the frame with this function:

```
document.getElementById('d').removeChild();
```

but it didn't work.
**how i can find it and delete it?**
It's suppose to block a web-frame until the time is over so that no one can click on the frame. So it creates a frame over the web-frame and I have a function to delete this frame because after sometime I need to be able click again on the original frame.

Comment: i think u need to delete 'd' not its child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this( A.removeChild(B).A is parent node of B, B is the node to delete)

```
 var node = document.getElementById("d");
            if (node.parentNode) {
              node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var ele = document.getElementById("d");
    ele.outerHTML = "";
    delete ele;
```

or

```
  var ele = document.getElementById('d');
      ele.parentNode.removeChild(ele);
```

Comment: What was it? Just curious.

Comment: it's stupid to say, but i forgot that i put a call to my function again in the code after deleting the frame so it was like this:
frame -> delete frame -> frame